# React Child is updating Parent State when manipulating the props in child. Unwanted

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-state

The below code is live at https://codesandbox.io/s/child-updating-parent-dont-want-pfdxd
The issue I am facing is that when I sort on child component(page2), it also updates state on the parent component(App). I want to avoid state update as the other child component(page 1) should display the unsorted data. I thought about having two states with the same data(two names and two numbers) on App.js.  Then use 1 set of states(name and numbers)for page 1 and the other set for page2.This seems redundant and unnecessary but I am not sure how to avoid the state update when sorting on page 2. Is there a way to avoid the state update when manipulating the data in the child component?

```
/*Parent*/  
    class App extends React.Component {
      constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
          numbers: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
          names: ["john", "sally", "bill", "rebecca"]
        };
      }
      render() {
        const { numbers, names } = this.state;
        return (
          <Router>
            <div className="App">
              <Header />
              <Switch>
                <Route
                  path="/page1"
                  exact
                  render={(routeProps) => (
                    <Page1 digits={numbers} people={names} {...routeProps} />
                  )}
                />
                <Route
                  path="/page2"
                  exact
                  render={(routeProps) => (
                    <Page2 digits={numbers} people={names} {...routeProps} />
                  )}
                />
              </Switch>
            </div>
          </Router>
        );
      }
    }
    export default App;
```

Here is the first component that receives the props

```
/*child 1*/
const page1 = ({ people, digits }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>
        Number Should Be "1" And Name Should Be "john" On This Page Regardless
        Of Sort On Page 2
      </h1>

      <p>Number: {digits[0]}</p>
      <p>Name: {people[0]}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
export default page1;
```

Here is the second component that receives the props

```
/*child 2*/

    const Page2 = ({ people, digits }) => {
      /* when uncommented the sort will also change state on App.js --- 
      I want state on App.js to remain in original state aft sorting*/
    
      /* --- UNCOMMENT BELOW TO SORT --- */
    
      /*people.sort((a, b) => b.toLowerCase().localeCompare(a.toLowerCase()));
      digits.sort((a,b)=>b-a)*/
    
      return (
        <div>
          <h1>
            Number Should Be "10" And Name Should Be "sally" On This Page When Sort
            Is Uncommented
          </h1>
          <p>Number: {digits[0]}</p>
          <p>Name: {people[0]}</p>
        </div>
      );
    };
    export default Page2;
```

Comment: In react props are immutable. You are mutating props with the array `sort` method. `sort` does not return a new array it mutates the existing one, this is why your state is changing.

Comment: do I need to set the sort to a variable? suggestions on how to avoid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Javascript, `sort` method performs in-place sorting. So, when you are performing `people.sort`, you actually end up modifying the passed `people` prop. Since arrays are passed by reference, every other reference of `people` will show up the new sorted value.

To fix this, You should mutate a local copy of the passed prop to prevent such unexpected outcomes.

```
const Page2 = ({ people, digits }) => {

  const sortedPeople = [...people].sort((a, b) => b.toLowerCase().localeCompare(a.toLowerCase()))
  
  const sortedDigits = [...digits].sort((a,b)=>b-a);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>
        Number Should Be "10" And Name Should Be "sally" On This Page When Sort
        Is Uncommented
      </h1>
      <p>Number: {sortedDigits[0]}</p>
      <p>Name: {sortedPeople[0]}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Page2;
```

To further explain whats going on in the above approach,

Instead of directly mutating the prop, we are now creating a copy of the array, in this case `people` and `digits` by using a ES6 spread operator like this `[...people]` and sorting on this new copy.

```
const sortedPeople = [...people].sort((a, b) => b.toLowerCase().localeCompare(a.toLowerCase()))
```

PS. You can also do `Array.from(people)` or `people.slice()` to achieve the same result.

Keep in mind, you can further optimise the rendering performance of this in React by using a `useMemo` hook and do something like this

```
const sortedPeople = useMemo(() => [...people].sort((a, b) => b.toLowerCase().localeCompare(a.toLowerCase())), [people]);
```

Comment: This is a great answer and works for my situation. Thank you so much!

Comment: Awesome. Upvote this answer too if it helped you so that this answer can help more people facing similar problems with their code.

Comment: I upvoted. It's just not showing up since I don't have 15 reputation. Thanks for the help again!